# split the time series data into intervals and count the frequency

Tags: r

I have this data and want to calculate frequency

```
1880-01-01
1951-01-01
1952-01-01
1976-01-01
1902-01-01
1919-01-01
1949-01-01
1814-01-01
1930-01-01
1920-01-01
1974-01-01
1925-01-01
1769-01-01
1949-01-01
```

and I want to output pattern like this

```
date        freq
 1890-1899    2
 1900-1909    3
 1910-1919    2
 1920-1929    2
 1930-1939    2
```

I have tried this code

```
MyDatesTable <- table(cut.Date(date_list$date, breaks="10 year"))
```

but I got output like this:

```
 date        freq
     1890    2
     1900    3
     1910    2
     1920    2
     1930    2
```

Comment: *I have tried this code* - Good. But what is the error that you recieved, logical/syntax? See what is a [mcve] and [edit] your post accordingly.

Comment: That's not particularly similar to what I get with a Date vector like that. The labels of the table are in YYYY-MM-DD format. I think you need to post data  , code, and output that match up. Furthermore the year boundaries are on the "9's" rather than on the "0's"

Comment: i want years in 10 year range like "1800-1810"